# React merge two states in third state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three state, two of them have data from different api and the third state need to merge those two states based on IDs. So, the third state should have every data that state1 have and state2 don't have, and every data that state2 have and state1 don't have.

Api1:

```
data: {
0: {
id: 1234
company: 'String',
name: 'Test'
}
1: {
id: 2345
company: 'String1',
name: 'Test 1'
}
2: {
id: 3456
company: 'String2',
name: 'Test 2'
}
3: {
id: 4567
company: 'String3',
name: 'Test 3'
}
}
```

Api2:

```
data: {
0: {
id: 1234
company: 'String',
name: 'Test'
lastName: 'Second'
}
1: {
id: 2345
company: 'String1',
name: 'Test 1'
lastName: 'Second 2'
}
2: {
id: 3456
company: 'String2',
name: 'Test 2'
lastName: 'Second 1'
 }
3: {
id: 4567
company: 'String3',
name: 'Test 3'
lastName: 'Second 3'
}
}

New Array should be (lastName = name + lastName :

data: {
0: {
id: 1234
company: 'String',
name: 'Test'
lastName: 'Second Test'
}
1: {
id: 2345
company: 'String1',
name: 'Test 1'
lastName: 'Second 2 Test 1'
}
2: {
id: 3456
company: 'String2',
name: 'Test 2'
lastName: 'Second 1 Test 2'
}
3: {
id: 4567
company: 'String3',
name: 'Test 3'
lastName: 'Second 3 Test 3'
}
```

Fetched Data:

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState([]);
const [state2, setState2] = useState([]);
const [mergeStates, setMergeStates] = useState([]);

useEffects(() => {
fetch("api1")
    .then(data =>{
        state1(data);
    })
fetch("api2")
.then(data =>{
    state2(data);
})

}, []);

useEffects(() => {
// Here I want to merge the responses based on IDs
const lastName = companies.map((response) => ({
  name: response.name,
  lastName: `${response.name} - ${response.lastName}`
}));
setMergeState(lastName);

}, [state1, state2]);
```

So, the api2 has lastName that api1 doesn't have. So, the mergedStates need to include that.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Also, why do you have an keyed object (that looks like an array) with ID keys inside them?

Comment: @Agney I have updated my request

Comment: As per the samples, API2 includes API1, so I don't get why you need to merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your quetion to merge the two state, you need to iterate over a state either 1 or 2, while merging them.

```
useEffects(() => {
 const keys = Object.keys(state1);

 mergedData = keys.map(key => {

  // key will be 0,1,2 as with your quetion
   return {
    ...state1[key],
    ...state2[key],
    fullName: state1[key].name + state2[key].lastName

   };
  });

}, [state1, state2]);
```

Comment: what is mergedData? is a const??

Comment: it could be anything, in this case yes its a const

Comment: it's work. How can I combine name + lastName in one? Check my question, I have updated.

Comment: beware if state1 and state 2 objects contain duplicate values, they will override each other, also. no worries, glad to help